# I am trying to read and write to firebase based off already created references

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOqS2.png)

I have a userProfile file:

```
class UserProfile {
    var uid:String
    var email: String
    var username:String
    var photoURL:URL

    init(uid:String, email:String, username:String, photoURL:URL) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.email = email
        self.username = username
        self.photoURL = photoURL
    }
}
```

and a Post file

```
class Post {
    var id:String
    var author:UserProfile
    var text:String
    var timestamp:Date

    init(id:String, author:UserProfile, text:String,timestamp:Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.author = author
        self.text = text
        self.timestamp = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)//divided by 1000 because firebase stores dates as milliseconds
    }
}
```

This is the way it shows in firebase[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCzeX.png)

So what I'm trying to do is reuse the references(username, date, and urlimage) that the two files before uses.

Here the code thats used for the post file:

```
func oberseverRoomatePostFeed(){

     let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

             var currentUserRoomatePose = [Post]()//temporary array

            //array****************************
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let roommateSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = roommateSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],

                let author = dict["author"] as? [String:Any],
                    let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
                    let photoURL = author["photoURL"] as? String,
                    let email = author["email"] as? String,
                    let username = author["username"] as? String,
                        let url = URL(string:photoURL),
                        let text = dict["text"] as? String,
                        let timeStamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double{

                    let userP = UserProfile(uid: uid, email: email, username: username, photoURL: url)
                    let post = Post(id: roommateSnapshot.key, author: userP, text: text, timestamp: timeStamp)
                    currentUserRoomatePose.append(post)
                }
            }
            self.posts = currentUserRoomatePose
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
}
```

And here is what I have so far

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var currentUser: UserProfile
    var currentPost: Post

    init(dictionary: [String: Any], currentUser:UserProfile, currentPost:Post) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.currentUser = currentUser
        self.currentPost = currentPost
    }
}
and
    func fetchUser() {

        let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")
            postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

                var currentUsers = [User]() // temp array
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    if let userSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = userSnapshot.value as? [String: Any],

                        let author = dict["author"] as? [String:Any],
                        let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
                        let photoURL = author["photoURL"] as? String,
                        let email = author["email"] as? String,
                        let username = author["username"] as? String,
                        let url = URL(string:photoURL),
                        let text = dict["text"] as? String,
                        let timeStamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {

                        let userP = UserProfile(uid: uid, email: email, username: username, photoURL: url)
                        let user = User(dictionary: [String : Any], currentUser: userP, currentPost: Post)
                    }

                }

            })
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGtsL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kkzf.png)

```
func checkLogin() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        perform(#selector(backButton), with:nil, afterDelay:0)
    } else {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        Database.database().reference().child("Users/profile/").child(uid!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["username"] as? String
            }
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
}


  "Users" : {
     "kFjK5Kcrk7dLCnd3fQOnhBcPQHz1" : {
        "Email" : "cmhughes95@gmail.com",
        "Full Name" : "Cameron Hughes",
        "Google UID" : "112185374105612274429",
        "provider" : "Google"
     },
     "profile" : {
        "0Ef8GJch5PPZ8yE9jLSXAS7fVoK2" : {
        "email" : "teclarke@aggies.ncat.edu",
        "password" : "Tecl6013",
        "photoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aggie-wallet.appspot.com/o/user%2F0Ef8GJch5PPZ8yE9jLSXAS7fVoK2?alt=media&token=62827fc7-38ec-47ae-9972-c078ef1d486e",
        "username" : "tec95"
      },
        "EsqtPIFUWQbXh0ItLWK0W3qxOdI2" : {
        "email" : "teclarke@aggies.ncat.edu",
        "password" :    "Tecl6013",
        "photoURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aggie-wallet.appspot.com/o/user%2FEsqtPIFUWQbXh0ItLWK0W3qxOdI2?alt=media&token=40c82e6e-cc4d-4320-a0ab-434cc297567a",
        "username" : "tyrek95"
      },
```

Comment: You don't need *var currentUserRoomatePose = [Post]()//temporary array*. The post object can just be appended onto the array *self.posts.append(post)*. However, ensure you reset it before use before *self.posts = []*

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; what does *the two files before uses.* mean?

Comment: I uploaded two images, one of firebase. I am trying to Access "Users", then "profiles" and then the user name so that I can have it listed at the titelbar like how it is in the second bar. I will upload the code I have.

Comment: Ouch. Please do NOT include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Are you wanting to get one username or all the usernames?

Comment: @Jay, Just one username for the title bar. then eventually I would want to get all usernames. But first I have to figure out why its crashing. I'm thinking its crashing because I'm not calling to the references correctly.

Comment: @Jay sorry about that and I'm uploading that now.

Answer (score 0):

Right off, there appears to be an issue with the users node. You've got what looks like a uid at the same level as a node called 'profile' which then contains other user id's. That's not going to work. The uid's should all be at the same level. The nodes also contain different child nodes so it's unclear what the purpose is. This would be a better structure:

```
users
   uid_0
     email: "test@test.com"
     photoURL: "https://www.xxxxxx"
     username: "tyrek95"
   uid_1
     email: "yipee@yipee.com"
     photoURL: "https://www.yyyyy"
     username: "someusername"
```

Based on comments, it appears you're trying to get a single user name to put in a titlebar - there's a whole lot of extraneous code in the question if that's the task. The checkLogin and fetchUser functions aren't called and while denormalization in the posts node is fine, it's unnecessary duplicate data - you don't need to have the email, photoURL duplicated as you know the uid and can get that from the users node

A better structure is

```
posts
  post_0
    author: "uid_0"
    text: "Hello, World"
    timestamp: "some time"
  post_1
    author: "uid_1"
    text: "What's happening?"
    timestamp: "some time"
```

To keep it simple, let's get one post and the associated user and print out what that user said in their post.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
let postNum = "post_0"
let postToGetRef = postsRef.child(postNum)
postToGetRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { postSnap in
    let postDict = postSnap.value as! [String: Any]
    let uid = postDict["author"] as! String
    let postText = postDict["text"] as! String
    let userToGetRef = usersRef.child(uid)
    userToGetRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { userSnap in
        let userDict = userSnap.value as! [String: Any]
        let userName = userDict["username"] as! String
        print("\(userName) said \(postText)") //here you put the name in the title bar
    })
})
```

and the output is

```
tyrek95 said Hello, World
```

I did this for a single post but it could be easily expanded by using .value on the posts node, which will read in all of the posts, and then iterate over them in a for..loop to get the post information and the user for each post.

Note there's no error checking here for brevity.